# Duplicate symbols in iOS using PJSIP and VLC

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I am building a react-native app which requires both VLC and PJSIP. The code works fine on Android but on iOS, I am getting a conflict of duplicate symbols while linking. It shows the following error:

> duplicate symbol _srtp_create in:
>       /vlc/MobileVLCKit-binary/MobileVLCKit.framework/MobileVLCKit(libvlc_srtp_la-srtp.o)
>       /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bee-afimekrxplarzrfgyjgzoqwbrfqt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRTCPjSip.a(srtp.o)
>   duplicate symbol _MD5_Init in:
>       /vlc/MobileVLCKit-binary/MobileVLCKit.framework/MobileVLCKit(md5.o)
>       /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bee-afimekrxplarzrfgyjgzoqwbrfqt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRTCPjSip.a(md5_dgst.o)
>   duplicate symbol _MD5_Final in:
>       /vlc/MobileVLCKit-binary/MobileVLCKit.framework/MobileVLCKit(md5.o)
>       /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bee-afimekrxplarzrfgyjgzoqwbrfqt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRTCPjSip.a(md5_dgst.o)
>   duplicate symbol _MD5_Update in:
>       /vlc/MobileVLCKit-binary/MobileVLCKit.framework/MobileVLCKit(md5.o)
>       /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Bee-afimekrxplarzrfgyjgzoqwbrfqt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libRTCPjSip.a(md5_dgst.o)
>   ld: 4 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

I have tried building PJSIP without SRTP but that doesn't help either as MD5 is required by both VLC and PJSIP.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: delete derived data from your mac and try running another time.

Comment: I did that multiple times. Didn't work.

Comment: did you additionally added /vlc/MobileVLCkit framework in your project? the error is the md5_dgst.o library presents in both library file libRTCPjsip.a and MobileVLCkit framework. just try by removing MobileVLCkit framework once.

Comment: Removing the framework builds it. But I need both the libraries in the project. Is there any way by which I can include both the static libraries?

Comment: No, you cannot, unless you rename some of the symbols. However, you can link either VLC or SIP dynamically instead of statically to solve that problem easily.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I figured out the solution. If someone is struggling with the same, dump VLCkit from the project and use [react-native-pxplayer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pxplayer) instead for iOS. You might need to build the FFMpeg library separately. You can download pre-built libraries for FFMpeg-iOS and integrate in your project. This solution works for integrating both RTSP and PJSIP in a single iOS application.

Note that VLC and PJSIP works together in Android without any issues.